Film about an Alien smaller than human attacked by a cockroach
80s/90s Film  watched as a kid
Chronologically:
A space cop, or a bounty hunter, who has a human form but is much smaller than Earth humans, arrives on Earth at the home of a lone woman. He wields a powerful pistol and is attacked by a cockroach and shoots off the leg of a table in the kitchen of the woman. He is after a space criminal - who is just a head (presumably lost limbs and body in previous battles), so he is just a head floating on some kind of anti-gravity skateboard or something. And wounds that the pistol of the cop/bounty hunter makes are incurable - non-stop bleeding. I really don't remember the end of the film, I remember that the alien criminal was trying to team with an Earth criminal and was smashed by him in a quarrel.
Any help identifying this movie highly appreciated!

I'm assuming you saw it in the 80's or 90's based on your tags?  Was it American?

It must be Dollman

Brick Bardo (Tim Thomerson) is a traveller from outer space who is
  forced to land on Earth. Though regular sized on his home planet, he
  is doll-sized here on Earth, as are the enemy forces who have landed
  as well. While Brick enlists the help of an impoverished girl and her
  son, the bad guys enlist the help of a local gang. When word leaks out
  as to his location, and all hell breaks loose. Brick is besieged by an
  onslaught of curious kids, angry gang members, and his own doll-sized
  enemies, and he must protect the family who has helped him and get off
  the planet alive. IMDb

Even Dollman have cameo in Bad Channels, and crossover sequel 1993's Dollman vs. Demonic Toys.

Oh, thanks so much, this is the right title - I've been looking for it for years!

@Chromeeda remember to accept and upvote when its right
